# how to add two rotation with different pivots on a imageView in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was trying to do rotations on an `ImageView`, each of which has its own `pivot`. One is meant to have default pivots while the other has (0, 0) as its pivots. While trying to do this, only the last rotation is done on the view. How can I have them both work simultaneously?

Here is my attempt:

```
  this.animate().rotation(180f).setDuration(0);
  setPivotX(0);
  setPivotY(0);
  this.animate().rotation((float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)))).setDuration(0);
```

This is done inside a function of a class implementing `imageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ParallelTransition, here is my example for it:

```
ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition();

    RotateTransition rx=new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(5), this);
    rx.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);

    RotateTransition rz=new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(5), this);
    rz.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);

    rx.setFromAngle(0);
    rx.setToAngle(90*xrotate);

    rz.setFromAngle(0);
    rz.setToAngle(90*zrotate);

    pt.getChildren().addAll(rz,rx);

    pt.play();
```